# Append value to each array in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of arrays, for example:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[10,20,30]])
```

Now lets say I want to extend each array with [4,40], to generate the following resulting array:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[10,20,30,40]]
```

How can I do this without making a copy of the whole array? I tried to change the shape of the array in place but it throws a ValueError:

```
x[0] = np.append(x[0],4)
x[1] = np.append(x[1],40)
ValueError : could not broadcast input array from shape (4) into shape (3)
```

Comment: You can't. Numpy arrays are not really designed to change size because it screws with having contiguous memory. It's probably more efficient to use lists until you have the final structure

Comment: I have edited my answer. It's not clear to me whether or not you can reformulate your problem to fit that use case, but it's worth considering.

Comment: `np.append` does not work in-place.  It's a version of `concatenate` and makes a new array.  It's a hard function to use correctly (if ever).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this. Numpy arrays allocate contiguous blocks of memory, if at all possible. Any change to the array size will force an inefficient copy of the whole array. You should use Python lists to grow your structure if possible, then convert the end result back to an array.

However, if you know the final size of the resulting array, you could instantiate it with something like `np.empty()` and then assign values by index, rather than appending. This does not change the size of the array itself, only reassigns values, so should not require copying.

Answer (score 2):

While @roganjosh is right that you cannot modify the numpy arrays without making a copy (in the underlying process), there is a simpler way of appending each value of an ndarray to the end of each numpy array in a 2d ndarray, by using [numpy.column_stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[10,20,30]])
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [10, 20, 30]])

stack_y = np.array([4,40])
array([ 4, 40])

numpy.column_stack((x, stack_y))
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10, 20, 30, 40]])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new matrix
2. Insert the values of your old matrix
3. Then, insert your new values in the last positions

   ```
   x = np.array([[1,2,3],[10,20,30]])
   new_X = np.zeros((2, 4))
   new_X[:2,:3] = x 
   new_X[0][-1] = 4
   new_X[1][-1] = 40
   x=new_X
   ```

Or Use np.reshape() or np.resize() instead

Comment: How is this more efficient than a copy?

Comment: `new_x[:, -1] = [4, 50]` is better `numpy` code.  And set the `dtype` of `new_X` to match `x`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I needed to avoid using double the storage space. I ended up converting the np.arrays into lists, modifying them, and then converting back.

Comment: @roganjosh You start your answer with "You can't". You can but is not efficient, and no, is not more eficient than a copy cause is a copy, but It's faster to copy than cast is Memory VS Time.

Comment: "How can I do this without making a copy of the whole array?". You can't. It will be copied. I don't know what point you're making. What you're doing is no different than a copy in principle, just less efficient still